# Error when trying to query All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I'm trying to query all subscribers through an SQL query.

I've copied a query which I am using in another instance of marketing cloud which works fine. However in the new instance the query activity is giving me an error:

> Errors: _subscribers is not a known data extension or system data
>   view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data
>   views.

does anyone know why its saying _subscribers is not a data view in the system?

Query is below -

```
SELECT
    sfdc.Id as SubscriberKey,
    sfdc.Email as EmailAddress,
    allsub.Status
FROM
    (SELECT con.Id, con.Email FROM Contact_Salesforce con WITH (NOLOCK)
    UNION
    SELECT lead.Id, lead.Email FROM Lead_Salesforce lead WITH (NOLOCK)
    ) sfdc
RIGHT JOIN
    _subscribers as allsub WITH (NOLOCK)
ON sfdc.Id = allsub.SubscriberKey
WHERE sfdc.Email != allsub.EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to query it in a child business unit of an enterprise account which is giving you this error. To fix it prepend “ent.” To _subscriber (I.e. ent._subscribers) or write the query in the top level BU.

In addition to this, you want to be querying the _ListSubscribers data view with ListID corresponding to your all subscribers list. You can get this by going to the all subscribers list and checking properties

Answer (score 2):

Just made a ticket with support.

turns out that data view querying was not provisioned for the account. Issue has been fixed after this was provisioned.